# How to embed matplotlib graph in Django webpage?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, graph

So, bear with me as I'm VERY new to Django, Python, and web-development in general. What I want to do is display a graph that I've made using matplotlib. I had it working to where the home page automatically redirects to the png of the graph (basically a tab in the browser with the graph displayed). However, now what I want is to see the actual homepage with the graph simply embedded. In other words, I want to see the navigation bar, etc. and then the graph in the body of the site.

So far, I've searched and I sort of have an idea of how to accomplish this. What I'm thinking is having a special view that simply returns the graph. Then, somehow accessing this png image from an img src tag in my template that I will use to display my data.

Graph Code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import datetime as dt
import pdb

def index(request):
    stock_price_url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/WIKI/PRICES.json?ticker=GOOGL&date.gte=20151101&qopts.columns=date,close&api_key=KEY'

    date = []
    price = []

    #pdb.set_trace()
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    json_root = json.loads(source_code)
    json_datatable = json_root["datatable"]
    json_data = json_datatable["data"]

    for day in json_data:
        date.append(dt.datetime.strptime(day[0], '%Y-%m-%d'))
        price.append(day[1])

    fig=Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    ax.plot(date, price, '-')

    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Price')
    ax.set_title("Google Stock")

    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    #canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Template Code:

```
{% extends "home/header.html" %}
  {% block content %}
  <p>Search a stock to begin!</p>
  <img src="home/graph.py" />

  {% endblock %}
```

What I'm getting now:

[Current Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7k3B.png)

Comment: Found the answer to my question [here.](http://www.extragravity.com/?entry_id=8)

Comment: could you kindly elaborate where I might find the solution in your given link? thanks :)

Comment: @sphoenix It's been a while since I've worked with Django but I believe it was this [here](http://www.extragravity.com/blog/2014/01/04/matplotlib-django/)

Answer (score 25):

I know this question is tagged as matplotlib, but I needed to do the same thing and I have found [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) to be easier to use and visually appealing as well. You can simply plot a graph and then in the view get the html code of the graph as :

```
# fig is plotly figure object and graph_div the html code for displaying the graph
graph_div = plotly.offline.plot(fig, auto_open = False, output_type="div")
# pass the div to the template
```

In the template do:

```
<div style="width:1000;height:100">
{{ graph_div|safe }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

I searched quite a bit until I found a solution that worked for me when it comes to rendering a matplotlib image on a Django page. Often, simply a lengthy string was printed instead of a visualization being produced. So, what finally worked for me was the following:

First, the imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
```

The dummy function **returning a graphic** is the following:

```
def return_graph():

    x = np.arange(0,np.pi*3,.1)
    y = np.sin(x)

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)

    imgdata = StringIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)

    data = imgdata.getvalue()
    return data
```

This one can be called by some other function using and rendering the image returned by `return_graph()`:

```
def home(request):
    context['graph'] = return_graph()
    return render(request, 'x/dashboard.html', context)
```

And in the `dashboard.html` file, the graphic is embedded by the following command:

```
{{ graph|safe }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should uncoment this line:

```
#canvas.print_png(response)
```

You can easily return plot using django HttpResponse instead using some extra libs. In the matplotlib there is a FigureCanvasAgg which gives you access to canvas where plot is rendered. Finaly you can simple return it as HttpResonse. Here you have very basic example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from django.http import HttpResponse

def plot(request):
    # Data for plotting
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
    ax.grid()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Comment: This is a simple and easy to understand response. I am trying to do the same as OP. I have my view pointing to a template which does a few things to display data from the model, but I am wondering how to incorporate this into that view? At the end I return return: "render(request, 'viewer.html', context), where context is the object from my model that i pass to the template [context = {'modelObj': modelObj, 'displayFields': form}]. how can i also send the graph like above, in addition to the context i already send? thank you in advance

Comment: Note that the above example can cause the following error: "ValueError: fname must be a PathLike or file handle". This question addresses some of the reasons for this happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542459/error-in-django-when-using-matplotlib-examples

Answer (score 2):

My setup:

```
Django==2.2.2
windrose==1.6.8
```

I am just sharing a solution I found online. I made it work with windrose and django (thanks to some article writer). And this

```
import base64
import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

flike = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(flike)
b64 = base64.b64encode(flike.getvalue()).decode()
return render(request, template_name='details_wind.html', context={'wind_rose': wind_rose_image})
```

In the template, show it as an image:

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,{{ wind_rose }}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed matplotlib figures to django-admin you can try [django-matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/django-matplotlib/) field. This field doesn't create a column in the database, but is rendered as a regular field. You don't need to customize/subclass `admin.ModelAdmin`, just use this field in your models and define how the figure will be generated.

Comment: with `django-matplotlib` you can render figures in the admin page, but not in the views - correct me if I'm wrong